# Flutter - Draw a triangle in bottom right corner using customPainter

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas

I'm trying to draw a triangle in the bottom right of the page. 
I've successfully created one in the top left doing like this:

```dart
    void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    // top left
    final pathOrange = Path();
    pathOrange.lineTo(0, size.height/3);
    pathOrange.lineTo(size.width/1.5, 0);
    pathOrange.close();
    canvas.drawPath(pathOrange, _paintOrange);
  }
```

But I can't find a way to do the same for the bottom right. I've read that apparently `canvas` is set to `0,0`by default, but I don't seem to be able to instantiate it twice, otherwise I would change the initial start using `canvas.translate`. 
I know that bottom-left coordinates are `0,size.height` and top-right `size.width,0`but I just can't get the bottom right one.
That's what the result should be

[image: end result]

And here what I've done
[image: what I've done]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add another path object and draw it again with canvas.

```
@override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paintOrange = Paint()..color = Colors.orange;
    final paintGreen = Paint()..color = Colors.green;

    final pathOrange = Path();
    pathOrange.lineTo(0, size.height / 3);
    pathOrange.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    pathOrange.close();

    final pathGreen = Path();
    pathGreen.moveTo(size.width, size.height);
    pathGreen.lineTo(0, size.height);
    pathGreen.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 1.5);
    pathGreen.close();

    canvas.drawPath(pathOrange, paintOrange);
    canvas.drawPath(pathGreen, paintGreen);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

First, you have to do a little math:

[image]

After you know where you need your points to be, you can draw your lines.

```
final pathOrange = Path();

// Create your line from the top left down to the bottom of the orange
pathOrange.lineTo(0, size.height * .3387);

// Create your line to the bottom right of orange
pathOrange.lineTo(size.width, size.height * .162);

// Create your line to the top right corner
pathOrange.lineTo(size.width, 0); // 0 on the Y axis (top)

// Close your line to where you started (0,0)
pathOrange.close();

// Draw your path
canvas.drawPath(pathOrange, _paintOrange);
```

Now repeat those steps with one addition: `moveTo`. By default your path will start at the origin (0, 0) top-left. However, you want it to start at a new location.

```
final pathGreen = Path();

// Create your line from the top left down to the bottom of the orange
pathGreen.moveTo(0, size.height * .978); // (100 - 2.8) / 100

// Create your line to the bottom left
pathGreen.lineTo(0, size.height);

// Create your line to the bottom right
pathGreen.lineTo(size.width, size.height); 

// Create your line to top right of green
pathGreen.lineTo(size.width, size.height * .6538); // (100 - 34.62) / 100

// Close your line to where you started
pathGreen.close();

// Draw your path
canvas.drawPath(pathGreen, _paintGreen);
```

Comment: Awesome answer that works too thank you! I've noticed that instead of `pathGreen.drawPath(pathGreen, _paintGreen);` it should be `canvas.drawPath(pathGreen, _paintGreen);` otherwise works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks for that. I've updated my answer. Also, if you haven't seen this article I highly recommend it: https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0

Comment: thanks for article, indeed despite many google research I didn't got on it, looks very complete thx!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this?

```
final pathBlue = Path();
pathBlue.moveTo(size.width, size.height);
pathBlue.lineTo(size.width, (size.height/3)*2);
pathBlue.lineTo(0, size.height);
pathBlue.close();
canvas.drawPath(pathBlue, _paintBlue);
```